# Creating R list as config object in JavaScript style

Tags: r, configuration, this, config

I need a config object to keep some constants being used in my R code. These are url for remote file, directory for keeping downloaded files, local filenames to be used after downloading, etc.
I'm R newbie that is why I decided to use JavaScript-like config object (particularly list) similar to something like this:

```
var config = {
    wd           : "/some/working/dir",
    zipSrc       : "http://www.example.com/remote_data_file.zip",
    data_dir     : "data",
    data_zip     : "data.zip",
    data_txt     : "data.txt",
    abs_data_dir : this.wd + this.data_dir,
    abs_data_zip : this.abs_data_dir + this.data_zip,
    abs_data_txt : this.abs_data_dir + this.data_txt
};
```

Notice that one can use "this" to reference current object and made some calculation/assignments right inside it.

The most distant place I reached in R is:

```
config <- list(wd           = getwd(),
               zipSrc       = "http://www.example.com/remote_data_file.zip",
               data_dir     = "data",
               data_zip     = "data.zip",
               data_txt     = "data.txt")
```

But what if one still needs to calculate abs_data_dir and other similar values? Is it possible to do that job while "building" config list object? Is it possible to derive new named list members based on just created ones like using mutate() in dplyr package? If so is there in R any analogue to JS' "this" to reference current object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1**

`within` comes to mind, I came to this after playing with it for a bit:

```
config = rev(within(list(), {
   wd           = "/some/working/dir"
   zipSrc       = "http://www.example.com/remote_data_file.zip"
   data_dir     = "data"
   data_zip     = "data.zip"
   data_txt     = "data.txt"
   abs_data_dir = file.path(wd, data_dir)
   abs_data_zip = file.path(abs_data_dir, data_zip)
   abs_data_txt = file.path(abs_data_dir, data_txt)
}))

config
# $wd
# [1] "/some/working/dir"

# $zipSrc
# [1] "http://www.example.com/remote_data_file.zip"

# $data_dir
# [1] "data"

# $data_zip
# [1] "data.zip"

# $data_txt
# [1] "data.txt"

# $abs_data_dir
# [1] "/some/working/dir/data"

# $abs_data_zip
# [1] "/some/working/dir/data/data.zip"

# $abs_data_txt
# [1] "/some/working/dir/data/data.txt"
```

You can turn this into a function:

```
list.eval <- function(...) rev(within(list(), ...))
```

to be called as follows `list.eval({a = 1; b = a})`.

---

**Solution 2**

Here is another function with a usage closer to `list`'s. It will also handle both named and unnamed arguments like `list` does:

```
list.eval <- function(...) {
   e <- new.env()
   argl <- as.list(sys.call())[-1L]
   naml <- names(argl)
   .eval.assign <- function(expr, name) {
      value <- eval(expr, envir = e)
      if (name != "") assign(name, value, envir = e)
      return(value)
   }
   setNames(Map(.eval.assign, argl, naml), naml)
}

z <- 10
list.eval(a = 1, b = z, c = a, 10)
# $a
# [1] 1
# 
# $b
# [1] 10
# 
# $c
# [1] 1
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 10
```

Comment: Solution 1 seems to be simpler and easier to understand for R novice. Thank you, flodel, very much!

Answer (score 1):

This may be less aesthetically pleasing than flodel's solutions, but you can work with environments rather than lists, e.g.:

```
mk_config <- function (expr) {
    env <- new.env()
    evalq(expr, envir = env)
    function (s) get(s, envir = env)
}
```

The syntax is less like `dplyr::mutate`: you just write a block of code:

```
CF_ <- mk_config({
    wd           <- "/some/working/dir"
    zipSrc       <- "http://www.example.com/remote_data_file.zip"
    data_dir     <- "data"
    data_zip     <- "data.zip"
    data_txt     <- "data.txt"
    abs_data_dir <- file.path(wd, data_dir)
    abs_data_zip <- file.path(abs_data_dir, data_zip)
    abs_data_txt <- file.path(abs_data_dir, data_txt)
})

CF <- function (e) CF_(deparse(substitute(e)))
```

One possible advantage of this is that `get`  fails with an error if you are missing a key rather than returning `NULL`:

```
CF(abs_data_txt)

## [1] "/some/working/dir/data/data.txt"

CF(abs_dtaa_txt)

## Error in get(s, envir = env) (from cf.R#4) : object 'abs_dtaa_txt' not found
## Calls: CF -> CF_ -> get
```

You can also load config options from a file with something like

```
local(source('config.R', local = TRUE), envir = env)
```

Comment: Very nice example of closure usage! Thank you, Samuel!